# Could not find or load qt plugin windows

Tags: windows, qt, dll

After having enough in searching and reading peoples questions that had the same problem as i have and trying allot of solutions that doesn't seems to help, I'm posting my question.

I want to run my project- qt application, it ran well when i built it on qt4.8.1 32bit and 5.1.1 64bit. now i want to run it on qt5.3.0 32 bit. i installed qt open source with the following configuration:
qt 5.3.0 msvc2010_opengl 32bit.

Since my projects is using qt solutions- qt single application and qt service, i downloaded the packeges, built it in the new environment and placed them in `qt/qt5.3.0/5.3/bin` and `qt/qt5.3.0/5.3/lib`.

(I mention this last detail because a simpler qt project that doesn't use these dlls- service and single application runs well in my environment).

Well, when I run my application from qt it doesn't run. When i run the exe file from the release folder i get the following error:

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the qt platform plugin "windows". reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

I tried all creative ideas:

note: I see that  automatically the build arainged the release folder with the folowing struck:
plugin folder with all plugins in it.
platform folder with the hole list of platforms:  `qwindows.dll, qminimal.dll`...
and also put straightly  the dlls: `qwindows.dll, qwindowsd.dll`

```
libEGL.dll
libEGLd.dll
```

`qt.conf` with the data:

```
[Paths]
Plugins=C:...\build-____-Desktop_Qt_5_3_0_MSVC2010_OpenGL_32bit-Release\release\plugins
```

I used the dependency walker that told me that the IEShims.dll is missind, so I brought it to the release folder from: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer.`

Now the dependency walker tells me:

> Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a
>   missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.

I see that the `Qt5core.dll->link checksum` member in the dependency is marked with red, and also I see it takes it from:

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.3.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin
```

so I bring to the release folder the Qt5Core.dll from: 
`C:\Qt\Qt5.3.0\5.3\msvc2010_opengl\bin.` then I get the following message:

> the procedure entry point
>   ?bytearrayToDouble@QLocalePrivate@@SANPBDPA_N1@Z could not be located
>   in the dynamic link library
>   c:/Qt/Qt5.3.0/Tools/QtCreator/bin/Qt5Gui.dll

so maybe its wrong to do so.

what else can i do???

Comment: There is, at least, one error in your qt.conf file - you have to use relative paths for your Plugins. As Qt docs state, "...All paths are relative to the Prefix. On Windows and X11, the Prefix is relative to the directory containing the application executable".

Comment: What sould i write under [path]?

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qt-conf.html